# destination file get corrupted in java if there is character like \n \u0039

Tags: java

I am copying some keys from one property file to another property file using java so if there is \n or \u0039 type data in source file it get distorted result in destination file how can i copy selected keys have \n value from source to destination

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far

Comment: Are you sure about this?  Do you realize that `\u0039` is the digit `9`?   Please provide an MCVE that shows how you are copying the file.  Include a sample file that gets corrupted when you copy it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

Load the source properties file:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (InputStream i = new FileInputStream("source.properties")) {
    p.load(i);
}
```

Remove those properties that aren't needed in destination file:

```
p.remove("propertyKey");
```

Or alternatively you can set up a new `Properties` object and copy properties there:

```
Properties p2 = new Properties();
p2.setProperty("key", p.getProperty("key"));
```

And finally write out the new properties file:

```
try (OutputStream o = new FileOutputStream("dest.properties")) {
    p.store(o, "some comments");
    // or p2.store(o, "some comments");
}
```

In this case if you have this in your `source.properties`:

```
a=b\nc
```

You will get the same in `dest.properties`:

```
a=b\nc
```